# Can annotation be added to decelerations

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

Can we add annotations to the decelerations instead to the getter methods.

I'm used to this

```
 @Column(name="Part_ID")
   public Long getPartId() {
   return partId;
 }
```

Can we use it like this

```
@Column(name="Part_ID")
private Long partId;
```

Thanks all.

Ravi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. See section [2.2.2.2 of the Hibernate annotations documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-property):

> By default the access type of a class
>   hierarchy is defined by the position
>   of the `@Id` or `@EmbeddedId`
>   annotations. If these annotations are
>   on a field, then only fields are
>   considered for persistence and the
>   state is accessed via the field. If
>   there annotations are on a getter,
>   then only the getters are considered
>   for persistence and the state is
>   accessed via the getter/setter. That
>   works well in practice and is the
>   recommended approach.

So if you put your `@Id` on a field, then Hibernate will look at annotations on the fields for the other properties. If you put `@Id` on a getter, then Hibernate will look at annotations on the other getters.